# What's the default value in an array after using malloc on a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc, typedef

Suppose I have this code :

```
typedef char BLOCK[10];
typedef struct {
  BLOCK block;
}Object;
```

And I do this :

```
Object* obj;
obj = malloc(sizeof(obj));
```

**My question :**
Will the array "block" have a default value in each of its cell ?

Comment: Formally, the memory is *indeterminate*.  (We sometimes say "random", but then we get people wondering why it's always the same.)  In practice, it will usually either be 0, or whatever the last caller left it as.  (By "last caller" I mean the last time some part of *this same program* called `malloc`, wrote some data to the memory region, then freed it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the 'error' in your code is just a typo (it should be `obj = malloc(sizeof(*obj));` or you will allocate enough space to hold a *pointer*), then there is nothing in the Standard(s) to specify what the allocated data will initialized to.

If you want **defined** initialisation behaviour, then you can use `calloc`:

```
obj = calloc(1, sizeof(*obj)); // Note: sizeof(obj) = pointer size but sizeof(*obj) is struct size
```

which will initialize all allocated bytes to zero.

Comment: `calloc()` takes two arguments.

Comment: There is text in the C standard regarding the content of the allocated memory: It is *indeterminate*, per C 2018 7.22.3.4 2.

Answer (score 0):

malloc() doesn't initialize the allocated memory.  See `man malloc`.

Comment: `man` pages document the implementation on their system, and not, in general, the specification of the C standard.

Comment: malloc() is a ANSI standard function, so its behaviour doesn't change from system to system.  Please see page 314 in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf.

Comment: The C standard specifies certain rules that `malloc` must conform to. These rules do not fully determine the behavior. For example, `malloc` could return cleared memory and still conform to the C standard. Or it could return memory deliberately filled with `0xdeadbeef` and still conform to the standard. Or it could, as some implementations do, provide various debugging features and still conform to the standard. Or it could, in case of failure, set `errno` to `ENOMEM` and still conform to the standard.

Comment: The man page on macOS states the latter, but this is not a property required of `malloc` as defined in the C standard. Therefore, the statements in the man page are not an accurate statement of what the C standard requires of `malloc`. If you write a C program relying on the contents of the man page, that program might not be portable to C on other systems or C implementations.